# google charts HTML annotations

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

With Google Charts, it is possible to have text annotations. I however require an image to be displayed.

Here's a JS fiddle (adapted from someone else's code) showing what I'm trying to do. http://jsfiddle.net/Lgn4T/

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotationText'});

data.addRows([
    ['Foo', 53, '<img src="bar.png"> Foo text', 'Foo description'],
    ['Bar', 71, 'Bar text', 'Bar description'],
    ['Baz', 36, 'Baz text', 'Baz description'],
    ['Cad', 42, 'Cad text', 'Cad description'],
    ['Qud', 87, 'Qud text', 'Qud description'],
    ['Pif', 64, 'Pif text', 'Pif description']
]);
```

Is this possible through annotations, or by other means? I need to use the line chart, so other methods would have to take this into account.

Comment: Check `tooltip.isHtml` and [enabling html tooltip...](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#enabling_html_tooltip)

Comment: A tooltip is only displayed when the user hovers over. I need annotations that are displayed all the time.

Comment: No, you cannot use images in the annotations.

Comment: My apologies, I spoke too soon.  It seems that HTML support was added relatively recently, but is not yet documented.  I will post an answer with an example shortly.

Answer (score 6):

After some experimentation, I determined that you can add images to the annotations, but only to the `annotationText` column.

In order to make the HTML annotations work, you must do two things: first, set the `annotationText` column's `html` property to `true`, and then set the chart's `tooltip.isHtml` property to `true`, like this:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotationText', p: {html: true}});

data.addRows([
    ['Foo', 53, 'Foo text', '<img src="bar.png"> Foo description'],
    ['Bar', 71, 'Bar text', 'Bar description'],
    ['Baz', 36, 'Baz text', 'Baz description'],
    ['Cad', 42, 'Cad text', 'Cad description'],
    ['Qud', 87, 'Qud text', 'Qud description'],
    ['Pif', 64, 'Pif text', 'Pif description']
]);

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, {
    height: 400,
    width: 600,
    tooltip: {
        isHtml: true
    }
});
```

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/7w2Hz/

Comment: This is nearly there. However I need the images to be displayed as annotations all the time, not only on mouseover. It may be that this isn't possible (feature request maybe needed).

Comment: No, it isn't possible in the API now.  You can make a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list) if you want.